# Add event handler to element in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i am working on a plugin for tinymce that adds an HTML-Element to the editor content...

This is how i insert the code:

```
let el = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.create('div', {'class': 'css-class'}, "this is the text");
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setNode(el);
```

Now i want to open a dialog if the user clicks on the new HTML-element.
I tried to add an event listener like this

```
el.addEventListener("click", function() {
console.log("clicked!");
});
```

but this does not do anything...

I am working with tinyMCE 5.x

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.eventutils/#bind

From Your perspective, the code should look like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.bind(el, 'click', (event) => {/* you function here */})
```

or

```
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.bind(el, 'click', function(event) {/* you function here */})
```

**EDIT**:
This is a working solution, though there should be a better way to do it

```
let el = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.create('div', {'class': 'css-class', 'id': "mydiv"}, "this is the text");
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setNode(el);
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.get("mydiv").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Please note that `get()` function from `dom` accepts element id without #

Comment: thank you, but this is not working. I used the Code:
`tinymce.activeEditor.dom.bind(el, 'click', (event) => function() {
console.log("clicked");
}
);`

Comment: well, the code you are using is not correct. Use either anonymous function or fat arrow function. I will update the answer

Comment: you are right. i changed the code to `tinymce.activeEditor.dom.bind(el, 'click', function() { console.log("clicked"); } );` but it is still not working.

Comment: this works. Tested on my machine
    `let el = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.create('div', {'class': 'css-class', 'id': "mydiv"}, "this is the text");
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setNode(el);
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.get("mydiv").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});`

Comment: i copied your code with no changes but i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.get("mydiv") is null

Comment: i have a pen for this: https://codepen.io/kili123/pen/RwKpvJp
The "infobox" button is for the new div but it gives me an "uncaught typeError" after trying to get() this element by id.

Comment: For some strange reason, your tinymce does not accept id, so I switched it to class
`let el = tinymce.activeEditor.dom.create("div", {
    id: "mydiv",
    class: "css-class"
  },
  "this is the text");
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setNode(el);
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select(".css-class")[0]
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that adds a click listener to content that exists in the editor:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/g9haab

I would note that you don't need to use any TinyMCE specific APIs to add a click listener - once you have content in TinyMCE it is effectively an HTML document in an iframe and you can interact with it just as you can any other HTML document.  The Fiddle has some default content in the editor when it loads:

```
<p>
  This is a paragraph of text that 
  <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;" id="target">
    contains a span
  </span>
   to add a click listener
</p>
```

...and then there is code in a setup function that looks for the `<span>` with the `id` of `target` and attaches a click listener using standard JavaScript:

```
const theTarget = editor.contentDocument.getElementById('target');
theTarget.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log('You CLICKED the text!');
});
```

Comment: thank you! Yes i know that it is possible to add eventlisteners without the editor classes but i want to write code that is understandable and easy to maintain, therefore i want to rely on the editors classes.
Also if i add the eventlistener on "init" it will ignore elements that i add later.

Comment: That is simply an example of how to add an event listener - there is no aspect of the code that requires it to happen on editor load.  You say you want to write code tthat is "understandable" - how is using standard JavaScript not understandable?